# rsync is deleting a protected folder

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm using

`rsync . $HOST:$PATH --itemize-changes --verbose --human-readable --times --checksum --recursive --delete --delete-excluded --force --filter='dir-merge .rsync-filter'`

and `.rsync-filter` looks like this:

```
exclude .gitinstructions
exclude .gitignore
exclude .rsync-filter
exclude .gitlab-ci.yml
exclude .git
exclude timestamp.txt
exclude var
exclude LICENSE.html
exclude LICENSE.txt
exclude LICENSE_AFL.txt
exclude RELEASE_NOTES.txt
exclude config.json

protect media/**/*
```

Although on the remote, the media folder is being deleted:

> $ rsync . $SSH_HOST:$SSH_STAGEPATH --itemize-changes --verbose
>   --human-readable --times --checksum --recursive --delete --delete-excluded --force --filter='dir-merge .rsync-filter' sending incremental file list .d..t...... ./
>   *deleting   media/test
>   *deleting   media/
>
> sent 680.12K bytes  received 28.00K bytes  472.08K bytes/sec total
>   size is 139.20M  speedup is 196.58

Am I missing anything? I basically want all the "excluded files/dirs" to not be uploaded, but deleted on the remote, and the "protected files/dirs" to not be uploaded and not be deleted. I was sure I am following the correct syntax from the man page.

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm the problem persists when you put

```
protect media/**/*
```

at the top of your `.rsync-filter` ?
In your example, it is at the bottom of the filter.

From the [rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> Note that if you are supplying your own filter rules, you may need to
> manually insert your own exclude/protect rule somewhere higher up in
> the list so that it has a high enough priority to be effective (e.g.,
> if your rules specify a trailing inclusion/exclusion of oq*cq, the
> auto-added rule would never be reached).

---

Comment: awh, i can't believe i missed that. i'll try it later on when a have a good time to test it. thanks.